Troubleshooting 403 Authentication Error in API Performance Testing using Jmeter
I am attempting to perform some performance tests on my application's API. When I send a request to the API, I am receiving a 403 (Authentication Error) response, but I am expecting a 200 (Successful) response.
The steps I have taken so far are:

I am sending a request to the API with valid parameters.

I am including a valid bearer token in the request.

I have verified that the URL is constructed correctly.

I have tested our health endpoint which does not need any authentication and this works correctly.


However, despite these efforts, I am still receiving the 403 Authentication Error response, instead of the expected 200 Successful response.
This suggests that there might be an issue with how I am setting up the bearer token in the request. It's possible that the API is not recognizing or accepting the bearer token I am providing, even though I believe it to be valid.
This is the code I am executing: (Code still needs to be cleaned up)
package initialization;

import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.JMeterEngineException;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;

import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JmeterSetup {
    private static final String API_URL = "";
    private static final String ACCEPT_HEADER = "*/*";
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Bearer ActualBearer";
    private static final String Param = "sd";

    @Test
    void givenJMeterScript_whenUsingCode_thenExecuteViaJavaProgram() throws IOException, JMeterEngineException {

        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(".\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-5.6.3\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
        String jmeterFile = ".\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-5.6.3\\bin\\jmeter.properties";

        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterFile);
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = getHttpSamplerProxy();

        LoopController loopController = getLoopController();

        ThreadGroup threadGroup = getThreadGroup(loopController);

        TestPlan testPlan = getTestPlan(threadGroup);

        ListedHashTree testPlanTree = new ListedHashTree();
        ListedHashTree threadGroupHashTree = (ListedHashTree) testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSampler);


        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");

        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        String logFile = "output-logs.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);


        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();


        System.out.println("Test completed. See output-logs.jtl file for results");
        System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at script.jmx");
    }

    private static LoopController getLoopController() {
        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();
        return loopController;
    }


    private static HTTPSamplerProxy getHttpSamplerProxy() {
        HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        httpSampler.setProtocol("https");
        httpSampler.setDomain("ApplicationDomain");
        httpSampler.setPath("Path");
        httpSampler.setMethod("GET");

        // Create a HeaderManager and add the headers
        HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
        headerManager.add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header("accept", ACCEPT_HEADER));
        headerManager.add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header("Authorization", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER));
        headerManager.add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header("param", Param));
        httpSampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);

        // Set the properties for the HTTPSamplerProxy
        httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
        httpSampler.setProperty(TestElement.NAME, "API Request");

        return httpSampler;
    }


    private static TestPlan getTestPlan(ThreadGroup threadGroup) {
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Sample Test Plan");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        return testPlan;
    }

    private static ThreadGroup getThreadGroup(LoopController loopController) {
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("Sample Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(10);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(5);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
        return threadGroup;
    }
}


I don't think this function really adds a HTTP Header Manager
httpSampler.setHeaderManager(headerManager);

you can use SaveService.saveTree() method to see how the resulting test plan will look like.
Instead you should do something like:
HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
headerManager.add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header("accept", ACCEPT_HEADER));
headerManager.add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header("Authorization", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER));
headerManager.add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header("param", Param));

threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSampler, headerManager);

More information: JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test

Hi @Ivan G I attempted this and still did not work.
